# Asyncio - create_task blocks thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a Python script that will receive messages from a websocket connection and every time it receives a new message, it needs to run an asyncio task in the background.

In order to "simulate" this process, i made a blocking functio that starts counting with a `while True` statement. The expected output is that every time a new message is received from the ws connection, a new count starts, but in my case, as soon as i run the script, the count function will block the whole code. How can i solve this?

Here is what i tried:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import time

#this is the blocking function..
def counter():
    count = 0
    while True:
        print(count)
        count += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
async def main():
    while True:
        try:
            async with websockets.connect('MY-URL') as websocket:

                while True:
                    msg = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), 500)
                   
                    try:
                        data = json.loads(msg)
                        await loop.create_task(counter())

                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two major problems here. Your first problem is, that you create an infinite loop in `counter` and than call it, when you try to pass it to `create_task`. This way `create_task` is never even called.
The second obvious problem is, that you try to pass a method to `create_task` while it expects a coroutine.
Define your `counter` method again as coroutine using `async def` and replace `time.sleep` with `asyncio.sleep` and I think it might work.

As a general note: You cannot have blocking code in the same thread as your event loop. This means never ever use `time.sleep` in asynchronous code...